# QR Code wordpress generate on page

Tags: php, wordpress, qr-code

i'm trying to add a QR to each of my sites with this code..

```
<img alt="QR code" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&amp;chs=150x150&amp;chld=L|4&amp;chl=&lt;?php the_permalink(); ?&gt;" width="150" height="150" />
```

but when i use a QR read on the code that it generate i only getting this

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

on the screen

someone how can help ?

Comment: unencode your html entities.

Comment: can you describe it a little more? :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP can't process the code since it's encoded.

Try:

```
<img alt="QR code" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&amp;chs=150x150&amp;chld=L|4&amp;chl=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>" width="150" height="150" />
```

Comment: @ThomasHansen try that.

Comment: now i get <?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?> ? :)